# How can i stop and disable a srvice in remote machines using powershell by parallel execution?

Tags: powershell

This can be used to stop a service:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -filter "name='IPEventWatcher'" -ComputerName Server01).StopService()
```

How can we execute the same parallely so that if the number of remote machine is more; the execution time can be reduced.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [PSParallel](https://github.com/powercode/PSParallel) module.

You would run it like this:

```
@("server1","server2") | Invoke-Parallel { [PSCustomObject] @{Server=$_;Result=(Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -filter "name='IPEventWatcher'" -ComputerName $_).StopService()}}
```